# Intent : Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using intent to start google maps. When I press the back key I want my application to get the focus.

Can you please let me know how can this be achieved??

Will using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag help??
I am not able to solve this.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What is happening now? Hitting the back button should go back to your app by default.

Comment: It remains in background.. It can be seen only after 4 back key clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you finishing the activity before you start google maps?  Program control should return back to your application if the user hits the back button as long as you don't finish the activity.

Comment: @Andrew and @ninjasense : when I click on back button , on one click I dont gte my application. First back click takes me to screen where it gives option to navigate , show on map. On clicking back again it takes where I can search route . If I click back again it shows map and then on clicking back again it is showing my applicaiton. So its almost 4 clicks. I want my app to be shown when back button is presses. Is there any way or someway to create shortcut??

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a way around that because program control is handed over to the Maps/Navigation app.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you can launch directly into Navigation/maps with the address you want instead of having the maps/navigation control it.  Example code here http://www.dbws.net/blog/2010/04/28/launch-an-intent-to-start-google-maps-in-navigation-mode/

Comment: ok, but I have to show path from source to destination.. how do I do it with navigate.. In link provided it just has one location.. can u plz elaborate

Comment: Intent myIntent = new Intent(
       android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,

       Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="
         + Addr1 + "+"
         + Addr2 + "+"
         + City + "+"
         + State + "+"
         + Zip));

     startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: Will geo work for navigation?I think its for maps.. but thanks anyway.. I think for navigation you can give only one address

Comment: by Addr1 and Addr2 I meant Address Line 1 and Address Line 2.  By hitting menu when the Maps activity opens, you can hit get directions.

Comment: but is there any way to specify source and dest.. like in maps we use &saddr and &daddr